# How to take a Snapshot in J2me with the MMAPI while using LWUIT

Tags: java-me, lwuit, mmapi

I want to make an application that takes a snapshot from Camera and send it to the server. I can do this pretty easily in Highlevel UI using MediaPlayer but it seem that I can't use the same code in LWUIT.

```
VideoControl vc;

Item videoItem = (Item) vc.initDisplayMode(vc.USE_GUI_PRIMITIVE, null);
```

Since it didn't work I used the MediaComponent.

```
MediaComponent videoItem =  (MediaComponent) vc.initDisplayMode(vc.USE_GUI_PRIMITIVE, null);
```

but it didn't work either. A class cast exception is thrown. Can you please tell me how to implement it.

Comment: @Duli-chan : can you give your code for sending the image to the server because I am working on a project for doing the same thing. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to call `initDisplayMode` for LWUIT. This is invoked internally by LWUIT, just add the video item to the LWUIT Form and the `initDisplayMode` method will be invoked for you.

Comment: How do I add it though? Calling new on MediaComponent?

Comment: There is some sample code in this LWUIT issue http://java.net/jira/browse/LWUIT-57 (that issue is resolved already).